# Is it safe to build for SDK 24?

Tags: android, gradle, android-7.0-nougat

I'm very used to creating apps that are for older versions of android, but recently I've been developing an app with a user base that is mainly SDK 19+.

I am going through trying to update my gradle depencies right now, and am wondering if I should up `compileSDKVersion` as well as `buildToolsVersion` to target Android N.

Everything in my app works, I don't have any desires to use the new features yet, I just don't like having outdated dependencies in my gradle file.

I'm sorry this is such a poorly worded question but I don't really know how else to put it.

Comment: With NDP4, [Google is comfortable with you doing these things](https://developer.android.com/preview/support.html#new): "You can now publish apps that use API level 24 to Google Play, in alpha, beta, and production release channels. "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Picking your compileSdkVersion blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd),

> Therefore it is strongly recommended that you always compile with the latest SDK. You’ll get all the benefits of new compilation checks on existing code, avoid newly deprecated APIs, and be ready to use new APIs.

As API 24 is the latest SDK, you should consider compiling with it. As stated in the same blog post, this does not mean you need to necessarily *target* API 24.